# Do not understand workflow of integrating Oauth into a rest API and Single Page Application

Tags: angular, django-rest-framework, auth0

I am trying to tie together my SPA, DjangoRestframework and auth0. I understand that the registration of users and logging the user in and out are all handled by Angular

**Some questions i really need help with:**
1. After the user registers on the client side, do we need to do something like: User.objects.create(**data).

2.If we do not create a user on our API how does the user's information get stored when we do something like Recipe.objects.create(user=request.user)?

3.If we are authenticated on the front end, we would surely have a token which carries the information of the user. Thus, when we use Http.post() what data about the user should we be passing alongside the data (eg: id_token, access_token)?

4.The documentation on auth0 are not very helpful to me as most of the things were done manually. Would there be anyone who can explain how all these work ? i have spent 2 entire days trying to figure out how to connect the puzzle but to no avail.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using OAuth terminology you will have:

1. Resource Owner - user that wants to authorize
2. Client - Your Angular SPA
3. Resource Server - Your Django backend/API
4. Authorization Server - Server that handles OAuth authorization/registration, this is Auth0 provider in your case

Actual Registration/Authentication is handled by Auth0, not Angular. Angular app will retrieve and store access token issued by Authorization Server (Auth0) to access Resource Server (Django API).

---

**Registration**

It is handled by Auth0, the client (Angular app) redirects user to Auth0 [customizable Sign Up page](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/custom-signup), it integrates with 3rd party providers like Facebook or Google, Auth0 can also persist user credentials in its own database.
You may want to store additional information in your backend during registration as well by sending additional requests to your Django API - questions #1 & #2

---

**Authentication**

There are several OAuth flows that you can use. It is recommended by Auth0 to use Implicit Grant flow for SPAs.

Implicit Grant:

1. When Resource owner (user) wants to login the Client (Angular app) initiates the flow and redirects the browser to Authorization Server - Auth0 (specifically to the /authorize endpoint), so the user can authenticate. The URL might look like this:

   `https://auth0.com/authorize?
   response_type=access_token&
   client_id=angular_client_id&
   redirect_uri=https://YourAngularApp.com/callback&
   state=123456`
2. Authorization Server - Auth0 authenticates the user with credentials if not logged in already. The first time the user goes through this flow a consent page will be shown where the permissions, that will be given to the Angular app, are listed (for example: post messages, list contacts, and so forth).
3. Authorization Server - Auth0 redirects the user back to the Client (Angular app) with an access_token (and optionally an id_token) in the hash fragment of the URI. The app can now extract the tokens from the hash fragment.
   E.g.

   `https://YourAngularApp.com/callback#
   access_token=kUsPx6ohjUD7UCtm&
   expires_in=86400&
   token_type=Bearer&
   state=123456`
4. Client (Angular app) can now append access_token when sending requests to Django API (Resource Server) - usually it's enough to only send access_token with client request for authorization - question #3

As for the question #4 I think Auth0 provides enough documentation to implement the flow properly:

[Auth0 Implicit Grant](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/grant/implicit)

[Auth0 Implicit Grant Tutorial](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/implicit-grant)